# How can i install ubunto 22.04.1 LTS on my VM 7.0.2 pack?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my VM 7.0.2 version and i received a warning message which says and I quote,

warning!
Error psyncing/closing/dev/sda:input/output error

with two box showing "Retry"  "Ignor"

What is the issue and what can I do to resolve this??

Comment: What is "my VM 7.0.2 pack"?

Comment: Virtual Machine or VirtualBox version 7.0.2

Comment: More details are needed. How are you trying to install?

Comment: You don't quote, unless some error message writer has very bad spelling.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.